# Talend Json API with parameter and Iterations

Tags: json, talend

I am trying to populate missing historical exchange rates. I have the missing value that I am pulling from the query and iterating and using the JSON API with the date parameter. However, it seems to be failing. I have attached the image below. [image]

Here is the paramter for the Json API. I have removed the accesskey key for privacy purposes:

```
"https://apilayer.net/api/historical?access_key=cdfsdfsdf&Date="+((Date)globalMap.get("row9.d"))+"&currencies=CAD&source=GBP&format=1"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly goes wrong? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @tobi6 It is not working. It fails on the connection and therefore not not retrieve any of the results. I am not sure If I am calling the URL correctly. Everywhere I have looked this is how it has been recommended to call the URL. Without defining the date and sending in the data parameter it works competently fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a `Date` to a `String` without using `SimpleDateFormat`. The usual output format is `yyyy-mm-dd` according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString()). This could work with your API or it could not. Depends. This means that the API call might use the wrong date format.

So, two steps are indicated:

**Visibility**

Add a **tJavaRow** directly before your **GBPToCAD** to inspect the values  (*don't forget to generate the code in tJavaRow first!*) and add something like the following:

```
System.out.println("https://apilayer.net/api/historical?access_key=cdfsdfsdf&Date="+((Date) globalMap.get("row9.d"))+"&currencies=CAD&source=GBP&format=1")
```

to check what the request actually looks like.

**Transformation**

Then I suppose you have to add `SimpleDateFormat`. It could look like this:

```
"https://apilayer.net/api/historical?access_key=cdfsdfsdf&Date=" + 
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").format((Date) globalMap.get("row9.d")) +
"&currencies=CAD&source=GBP&format=1"
```

Again, check the output in the **tJavaRow** component first and adjust the format to whatever format your API expects.

If everything is set, your call should work just fine.